# Override 336px Chrome Minimum Window Width

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, responsive-design

A recent update to Google Chrome (for Windows) has increased the minimum window width to 336 pixels. I can no longer test at 320px for mobile devices. I have installed the [Window Resizer Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh), but clicking on its smallest size only decreases the width to 336 pixels instead of 320. Is there any way to get around this new minimum, or do I have to switch to a different browser?

Comment: Chrome mobile emulation doesn't work for you? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation

Comment: I wasn't aware of that feature, but it is a pretty good work-around for the 320px size. Thanks!